# drop down menu open but when mouse hover on dropdown item ,dropdown menu close

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

i make drop down menu.
my HTML coding

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="#features">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#gallery">Projects</a></li>
    <li id="list"><a>Our Services</a></li> //on hover dropdown menu open
      //dropdown menu start
                <li class="dropbtn"><a href="iphone_app_development.html">IPhone App Development</a></li>
                   <li class="dropbtn"><a href="andriod_app_development.html">Android App Development</a></li>
                 <li class="dropbtn"><a href="website_development.html">Website Development</a></li>
                     <li class="dropbtn"><a href="graphics_designing.html">Graphics Designing 
                     </a></li>
                     <li class="dropbtn"><a href="game_development.html">Game Development </a>
                     </li>
                    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="it_security.html">IT Security</a></li>
                    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="virtual_reality.html">Virtual Reality</a></li>
//dropmenu end

            <li><a href="#testimonial">Client's Reviews</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
        </ul>
```

My CSS

```
.dropbtn
{
    display: none;
}
#list:hover ~ .dropbtn
{
    display:block;
}
```

dropdown menu work correctly but when mouse hover on dropdown item for example IPhone App Development option,list hide same issue all dropdown list why how select option between IPHONE... to Virtual Reality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap sub-menu on nested `ul`

```css
.dropbtn
{
    display: none;
}
#list:hover  ul#tset .dropbtn
{    display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="#blog">Blog</a></li>
 <li><a href="#features">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#gallery">Projects</a></li>
    <li id="list"><a>Our Services</a> 
      <!--dropdown menu start-->
        <ul id="tset">
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="iphone_app_development.html">IPhone App Development</a></li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="andriod_app_development.html">Android App Development</a></li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="website_development.html">Website Development</a></li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="graphics_designing.html">Graphics Designing 
    </a></li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="game_development.html">Game Development </a>
    </li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="it_security.html">IT Security</a></li>
    <li class="dropbtn"><a href="virtual_reality.html">Virtual Reality</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
<!--//dropmenu end-->

  <li><a href="#testimonial">Client's Reviews</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: should write css to align properly

Comment: i check both margin or padding but no any effect on drop downlist why